# ChangeLayoutMode(null, true): what are the parameter names?

Tags: 2010, development

This saves a page you're editing in SharePoint:

```
<a href="javascript:ChangeLayoutMode(null,true);">Save</a>
```

What are the names of the two parameters to this method? More important, what do they change about the method's behavior?

If you can, please cite a source.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This method actually calls `_MSOLayout_ChangeLayoutMode` declared in `IE55UP.js`. Signature for the method:

```
function _MSOLayout_ChangeLayoutMode(bPersonalView, bExitDesignMode) {...}
```

So, the first bool parameter indicates if you want to switch to personal view, and the second indicates that you want to exit from design mode.
Usually, this method used like follows:

-Switch to edit mode(none pesonal view):

```
ChangeLayoutMode(false);
```

-Exit from edit mode:

```
ChangeLayoutMode(null,true);
```

Take a look at this method in `IE55UP.debug.js` for better understanding.